# Authentication system - Return information that have to change every time

Tags: php, delphi, authentication, password-protection

I have a application (made in Delphi) that contains a Authentication system (login & password).

This system is in PHP, and the application get results from PHP using HTTP **GET** method.
The system returns 'OK' if login and password are correct, and 'NO' if not correct.

Like this...

```
procedure Check;
var
 x: string;
begin
 x:=Get('www.mywebsite.com/auth.php?user=xxxxxx&pass=zzzzzz');
 if x='OK' then 
  UnlockFeatures
 else
  MessageBox(0,'You're not VIP','Error',0);
end;
```

Well, it works fine, but it is very easy to circumvent this system with sniffers, packet editor or proxy.

**So, I want to get some information (in PHP) that changes every time, and that could be possible get the same information by my application.**

**What can I do?**

I don't need codes. Just tips, suggestions, please...

Thanks...

Comment: I agree with @jeroen about using post method and https. Additionally, you can make use of encryption and timestamp.First, request for timestamp from server. The server replies with timestamp encrypted. The client decrypt the timestamp & sends encrypted the username, pwd and timestamp to server. The server checks for the timestamp. The timestamp only valid for certain amount of time only (a few minutes). So, you can avoid replay-attack. If someone tries to resend the request, it will be expired. If all good, then the server sends back encrypted 'ok' msg.

Comment: Try to fidn some OpenID or OAuth implementations. When u deal with security - any tiny mistake that you can not spot may ruin all your framework. There were relatively simple OpenID v.1 there are, they say, overenginered beyond practicality, but still more or less standard OpenID v.2 and OAuth v.2. They already addressed those concernsm just implement them.

Comment: Thank you guys! Your tips surely will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally i suggest you not to try to outsmart everyone and invent brand new bicycle - you'd 99% fail with some stupid error making your approach completely insecure. There were a lot of precedences like DVD encryption or Win95 security. You'd better try some industry-approved mechanics, that for years been tested for security, that should have readymade implementations for both Delphi and PHP. Few are

- TLS (https:// protocol) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security - that would give no protection from [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks, but it sounds exactly what you asked and would require least possible change.
- You may try implementing [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) via [integrated windows authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) if you server would support that
- You may try setting up [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid) or [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) environments. Generally their v.1 would be simpler than v.2
- You may try to bail out of HTTP and use [XMPP/Jabber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) authentication - they take security seriously and libraries for PHP and Delphi exist. Though it should not be much more secure than just using TLS, you may hope that dumb attackers would not be prepared for non-HTTP protocols (there is not internet outside Facebook and such).
- You may use Bluetooth-like approach to make special connection("handshake") once (when both client and servers are controlled) just to make special "tokens" interchanged and stored.  That is a generic trait to use "controlled environment" to make 1st connection and use some tokens to prove "we had met before" on later connections using generic [challenge/response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response) trait. Those tokens should be unique for each client-user-server combinations! If you'd make one server-global clients-shared set of tokens - they would just be easily copied form one client to another and no more security remains.
- - Those may be coefficients for some not most trivial [RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNG). constructed be server and saved by both client and server. Then server "challenges" with RNG seed and client should response with proper random value, prooving he knows coefficients.
- - Those may be some [asymmetric crypto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_crypto), where token is some random "message", then server sends client encruyption keys and expects the correct message encrypted by them, or the token is the password and server generates random text and expects it's correct crypto digital signature to be passed back. You may find encyption libraries at [Torry.net](http://www.torry.net) for examples. [Lockbox3](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au) and Spring4Delphi are among most tested and noted crypto libraries for Delphi implementing some encrypting standards.

Consider you priorities and make your choice.
Would you be able to switch all the authentication layer in one key turn later, having absolutely no care for backward compatibility with non-updated clients, then you might choose the most simple one and only enhance it later if needed. If your users are lazy at upgrades then you'd better choose most secure approach from starters, since you would have no practical way to disable insecure implementation later.

Comment: WOW! So much alternatives, heh... I'll choose the best option for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Delphi (looooooong time ago...), but as far as the php and security is concerned:

- I would use `post` instead of `get` (and `https` if possible)
- If you can read php sessions with Delphi, you could add a session variable with a random number and add that as a hidden form field, send it in and check it against the session variable.

Comment: I already use https... I'll check the possibility of using POST instead of GET, thanks for the tips.